# Must a curve containing $(d^2+3d)/2$ lattice points contain another?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose a curve of degree $d$ in the plane passes through $\frac{d^2+3d}{2}$ lattice points. Must it pass through another lattice point?

Comment: I think you mean "Must the curve pass through another point of $\mathbb Z^2$?".  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I think so. Thank to You very much @LSpice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes if $d=1$, but no for $d\ge 2$.

[Schinzel's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleLatticePoints.html) says that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a circle with exactly $n$ lattice points on the circumference. In particular, there is a circle passing through exactly $5$ lattice points, not $6$, which is a counterexample in degree $2$: 
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 +y^2 = \frac{5^4}{9}$$

Circles containing more points can be used to construct reducible counterexamples with higher degrees, as can curves like $xy=m$ where we can control the number of factors of $m$.

Comment: Dear Dr. @DouglasZare,

I want to ask You  with modify question, could You answer me:

Let $z=f(x,y) \in R[x,y]$, deg $f = n$, If there exists $k =\frac{n^2+3n}{2}$ integral roots $(x_i, y_i)$ (ingeneral position) of $z$ is (then) there exist another integral point $(u,v)$ such that $z = f(u,v) \in Z$ ?

Comment: @Bùi Thị Lan: Exactly what do you mean by "in general position?" There are several possible definitions.

Comment: If the counterexamples above count as having integer roots in general position by whatever definition you are using, then only countably many multiples would take a nonzero integer value at a lattice point, so any other multiple is a counterexample to the modified version.